# Windows Phone how to avoid changing Visibility in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone and  I need to show element dependens on some condition(textbox or starRating ). I know that I can use  visibility converter But I know that changing visibility is refreshing the view but I have a lot of such elements (Longlistselector). My current XAML code you can see below.

Do I have any alternatives to avoid using visibility converter?

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                 Visibility="{Binding Title, ConverterParameter=textblock, Converter={StaticResource SortToVisibilityConverter}}" />
      <toolkit:Rating Value="{Binding Title}"
                      Background="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                      ReadOnly="True"
                      Visibility="{Binding Title, ConverterParameter=stars, Converter={StaticResource SortToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, "not" really. I say "not" because you can always manually toggle the visibility in the code behind. But that is strongly discouraged.

Use the converter, it works correctly with MVVM which is recommended in itself.